# Передаю ассоциативный массив в функцию в дополнение к строке

Tags: php

У меня есть класс методу которого нужно передать параметр -

```
$user = User::getInstance($id);
$user->set('work\new'.['role'=>'profession', 'address'=>'homeland']);
```

После в методе `'work\new'` использовать как ключи многомерного массива где хранится информация, а `['role'=>'profession', 'address'=>'homeland']` должно быть значением ключа `new`, либо создается новый ключ с данными значениями.

Структура массива :

```
Array
(
[name] => Name
[home] => Array
    (
        [city] => Санкт-Петербург
        [state] => Россия
        [location] => Array
            (
                [longitude] => 4565
                [latitude] => 55155
            )
    )

[work] => Array
    (
        [main] => Array
            (
                [role] => Treeman
                [address] => Address
            )

        [hobby] => Array
            (
                [role] => Meloman
                [address] => Address
            )

    )

[age] => 30
)
```

Проблема в том что в методе мой параметр выглядит так - work\newArray.
То есть функция `explode('.', $parametre);` возвращает

```
Array
(
    [0] => work\newArray
)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто сталкивался с этой проблемой, как можно решить её. Аргумент передается строго по этой форме.

Comment: У Вас есть класс, которому вы в метод set передаёте `work\newArray`, верно? Что за метод, что он не делает? Непонятно. Вероятее всего, вам нужно точку заменить на запятую. Но это не точно.

Comment: `$user->set('work\new'.['role'=>'profession', 'address'=>'homeland']);` - данная точка просто слаживает две строки. Если хотите воспользоваться методом `explode('.', $parametre);` то вставьте точку в строку, например так: `'work\new."`. Но вопрос в другом: если set - это функция, то в чем проблема сделать чтобы она принимала два параметра? и потом вызывать так: `$user->set('work\new'.['role'=>'profession', 'address'=>'homeland']);`

Comment: Если у вас в `$user->set` должен приходить только 1 аргумент, то оберните массив в `json_encode(array(...))`. В функции сделаете `json_encode(...)`. Но лучше всё же поменять сигнатуру функции `$user->set` на 2 аргумента

Comment: Нельзя менять условия задания. Если точку поставить в кавычки то с массивом тоже нужно будет в кавычки брать. Но в таком случае я не смогу сделать `array_replace($mainArray, ['role'=>'profession', 'address'=>'homeland']);`. При `explode('.', $string);` Второй элемент будет строкой всегда. По крайней мере у меня она так.